# Traceback error when using pipenv and either IDLE or PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv

I am running Python3.6.5 and have used pipenv to install requests. To test the install I to into the env by using 'pipenv shell' and then at the next prompt typing python. I then enter the code below:

```
Rs-MacBook-Pro:spacy myname$ pipenv shell

Spawning environment shell (/bin/bash). Use 'exit' to leave.
bash-3.2$ . /Users/myname/.local/share/virtualenvs/spacy-  JBK2xTM0/bin/activate (spacy-JBK2xTM0) bash-3.2$ python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:41:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
>>> print('Your IP is {0}'.format(response.json()['origin']))
```

and I get a good response.

I take the same three lines of code and put them into a script (requests.py) composed in either PyCharm or IDLE and when I run the script I get the following errors:

```
Rs-MacBook-Pro:spacy myname$ pipenv run python ~/requests.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/myname/requests.py", line 1, in <module>
      import requests
   File "/Users/myname/requests.py", line 2, in <module>
      response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to write a script that calls `requests` that is itself called `requests`?  Name it something else and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: @Patrick Thank you, unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Is there still some script that you've created named `requests` somewhere?  Have you deleted or renamed all the files you made called `requests`, closed python, and then tried again?  You may want to read up on how [`import` actually works](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: bingo!  I did not delete the original file requests.py, once I did that and restarted python it worked. Thank you very much